# crear tabla desde java que tiene una base de datos en access

Tags: java, jdbc, ms-access

me gustaria que una tabla , cuando yo quiera volviera a hacer incrementable desde 1, pero eh buscado en muchas partes y esto no se puede hacer desde java... aunque si alguien lo sabe pues seria magnifico , si me pudieran colaborar.
entonces volviendo al tema, como alternativa a esto aconsejan crear una tabla con los mismos campos y eliminar la otra.
pero no quiere crearse la tabla desde neatbeans.
sale este error
como pueden ver dice que hay un parentesis que no espera pero eh revisado mis parentesis y estan bien... me podrian colaborar y ver donde esta el eror por favor.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    try {



                           String name="ticket2";
        String Query = "CREATE TABLE " + name + ""
                + "(id int(10) not null auto_increment,primary key (id),cod VARCHAR(50), nombre VARCHAR(50),kilox VARCHAR(50), precio VARCHAR(50),peso VARCHAR(50),total VARCHAR(50))";



                         connection=con.conexion();
                   ps=connection.prepareStatement(Query);
                   ps.execute();  
                   ps.close();


           }catch (SQLException e){
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error al eliminar producto de venta,Error de sistema, comuniquese con proveedor: "+e);
           }
```

Comment: Claramente te dice que es una Exception producida desde Access, osea, la sintaxis utilizada no es correcta. En la respuesta te coloco la porción de código que debes utilizar.

Comment: @anma1d: No se deben colocar etiquetas en los títulos, en particular debe evitarse "Solucionado" ya que este sitio no es para la solución de problemas particulares (del interés de una sóla persona). Las pregutnas / respuestas deben tener el potencial de ser de interés a muchos usuarios.

Answer (score 2):

Prueba esto:

```
try {
    String name="ticket2";
    String Query = "CREATE TABLE " + name
        + " (id Counter Primary Key,cod TEXT(50), nombre TEXT(50),kilox"              
        + " TEXT(50), precio TEXT(50),peso TEXT(50),total TEXT(50))";

    connection=con.conexion();
    ps=connection.prepareStatement(Query);
    ps.execute();  
    ps.close();
}
catch (SQLException e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error al eliminar producto de"
    + " venta,Error de sistema, comuniquese con proveedor: "+e);
}
```

Lo que pasa es que estás mezclando sentencias utilizadas en postgres, por ejemplo, **Counter** es la directiva para hacer auto-increment en access, y la que usas se utiliza en postgres. Lo mismo con el tipo de datos VARCHAR, DEBES UTILIZAR **TEXT**.

Comment: carlos gracias . pero ahora me sale otro error: Cannot write indexex of this type due to unsupported collating sort order SortOrder[3082(0)]for text index(Db=POS.accdb;table=MSysObjets;index=0)                         porque pasara esto???

Comment: ahh si es necesario mi base de datos se llama POS , esta esta dentro de una carpeta llamada BD. aclaro que las demas consultas insertar  eliminacion y modificacion si funcionan, osea que la conexión esta bien ... agradezco su ayuda

Comment: Bueno, proba con una cosa, abrí tu Access, anda a Opciones Generales, y fijate en algún lugar debe decir New Database sort order. El valor debe ser General - Legacy. Y fijate si ahí funciona

Comment: listo carlos ya lo hice de echo buscando el error, dicen que haga eso y compacta y repare ya hice eso tambien y nada que pasara :´´(

Comment: ya encontre la solucion hay que en access configurar la direccion de confianza aqui dejo el link de como hacerlo, casi me saco un ojo , pero muchas gracias tu me guiaste mucho ubiera pensado que era cosa del codigo no mas ...  https://support.office.com/es-es/article/Evitar-que-el-modo-deshabilitado-bloquee-una-consulta-0171e2dd-f9b0-4ffa-a542-2278ce1babb1#bm2    buscan en Habilitar una base de datos de forma predeterminada ;)

Comment: De lujo, que bueno que pudiste solucionarlo. Exitos!